# Regex Match String Outside of Quotes, if the quote is incomplete, do not match anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, expression

The results I want:

1. `T1 T3 T5 T8 "` = no match since the quote is incomplete or even better, match characters before the quote
   1a. `T1 T3 T5 T8 "T4` = match T1 T3 T5, ignore T4 = not a requirement but would be nice if this can be achieved as well
2. `T1 T3 T5 T8 "T9"` = match only T1 T3 T5 T8, ignore T9
3. `O2 T3 O5 "T7 T9" O8` = match O2 T3 O5 O8, ignore matches within the quote

This is the regex I have so far, but I can't make it mismatch everything if the quote is incomplete.

```
/(^|\b)(t|o)\d+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")[^"]*$)/gi
```

Comment: would you be okay with non-regex solution?

Comment: @gurvinder372 only if this is impossible to do in regex. I have most of it working, just the part where I don't want it to match if the quotes are incomplete

Comment: If all you have is a regexp, then everything looks like a /^[Nn]ail$/

Comment: Is `"1a" at updated post opposite of requirement at "1" ?

Comment: @guest271314 yeah but I don't know if thats possible so its not a requirement, but an enhancement. 1a is optional. The most basic thing I want is if the quote is incomplete, do not match anything.

Comment: Are words always  2-characters long?

Comment: If you want challenge yourself, you are welcome to do 1a. If the quote is not matched, match anything before the quote but not the rest until the quote has been closed.

Comment: @MaxZoom No, numbers that follow the letters could be long. Think of the T1 T2 T3... as table columns in the db. In reality, they will be more like:  T1 AND T200 OR O212 AND "T2 OR T3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for what you posted use this pattern

```
"[^"\r\n]*"|"[^"\r\n]*$|(\w+)
```

and check against sub-pattern #1
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA7oP0/3)

Comment: Yep, this worked. I was able to get to the correct solution by this solution. I edited it slightly to this:   /"[^"]*"|"[^"]*$|((t|o)\d+)/gi.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a two step validation:

```
a = YourString
a.match(/\"[^\"]+\"/) ? a.replace(/([^\"]*)\".*\"([^\"]*)/,"$1$2") : ""

a='T1 T3 T5 T8 "'
# ""

a='O2 T3 O5 "T7 T9" O8'
# "O2 T3 O5  O8"

a='T1 T3 T5 T8 "T9"'
# "T1 T3 T5 T8 "
```

**UPDATE**
To cover the not required case, just add another condition

```
a.match(/\"[^\"]+\"/) ? a.replace(/([^\"]*)\".*\"([^\"]*)/,"$1$2") : a.replace(/([^\"]*)\"[^\"]*/,"$1")
```

Comment: I like this approach, but the problem I ran into while implementing is that I need to get the matched term's index position. During replacement, the original index is off because the variable length no longer match what is on the textarea after replacements. I will further try to go with this approach and try to resolve my problem on getting the correct index position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

https://regex101.com/r/bA7oP0/1

```
 /([^\"]*)\".*\"([^\"]*)/gi
```

Comment: Allright. I achieve that for the first case but it matches all string, not the requirements (not match anything): `/([^\"]*)\".*(?!\")([^\"]*)/gi`

Comment: Could you incorporate the actual string match with either T or O in this. I tried editing your regex by replacing .* with this but it didn't work. Regex is just my huge weakness.

Comment: Yeah, here you are: https://regex101.com/r/bA7oP0/2 `([o|t][^\"]*)\".*\"([^\"]*)`

Comment: I couldn't do replace since I needed to get the position. So I looked at your solution again and noticed the version 3. I am not sure if you added the version 3 but I slightly modified it to the following from:
/"[^"\r\n]*"|"[^"\r\n]*$|(\w+)/gm
to:
 /"[^"]*"|"[^"]*$|((t|o)\d+)/gi

This I believe worked in all cases.

Comment: I don't make the third version, but if it fits with your requirements follow it!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a `replace` and then a conditional `split`:

```
// case 1
var str = 'O2 T3 O5 "T7 T9" O8';
var r = str.replace(/\s*"[^"]*"/g, '');
var m;

if (str != r)
   m = r.split(/\s+/);

console.log(m);
//=> ["O2", "T3", "O5", "O8"]

// Case 2
var str = 'O2 T3 O5 "';
var r = str.replace(/\s*"[^"]*"/g, '');
var m;

if (str != r)
   m = r.split(/\s+/);

console.log(m);
//=> undefined
```